# Where to ask Voice Recognition questions

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm not even sure this is the right place to ask this question! Let alone where to ask any questions. As you can probably figure, I'm very new to the StackExchange family of sites, but I'm very eager to join in. I'm mainly interested in speech recognition and web development questions. I think I can figure out where the latter goes, but not so sure about the former. Any advice?

EDIT: I am mostly interested in creating custom scripts for Dragon v14 and Vocola, I am an endeavoring web developer and I use Dragon with my code editor, so questions on integrating direct recognition into my programming work would be normal, as would questions on working vbs scripts and scripts for vocola.
 I'm not sure what example questions I could ask, I'm coming up kind of black right now sorry xd I might edit again later if need be when I think of some.

Comment: Welcome to the network! What exactly are you hoping to ask? Could you give one or two example questions? There are a few sites where these might fit in, so I want to make sure we point you in the right direction.

Comment: http://knowbrainer.com/forums/forum/index.cfm

Answer (score 1):

If you have specific programming quesions, Stack Overflow has a [speech-recognition](/questions/tagged/speech-recognition) [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/speech-recognition) with a large number of questions in it. From the sounds of your question it seems that this is more likely where you should be. Check out some of the questions on the tag that are upvoted and have upvoted answers to see whether yours would fit.

If your question is more about algorithms of speech recognition, the [same tag](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speech-recognition) exists in [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) but for that slightly different purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Robert said, there are a couple of voice-recognition tags in sites like Stack Overflow. However, Ask Different has a tag for Siri and Dictation, and I'm sure there are many other specifics.